# Export curves to SVG missing in 4.0. Is there an alternative workflow?

Tags: interface, export, add-on, svg

Is this a bug or some feature that I haven't read about?  In 3.6 and earlier there is the menu option to export curves to SVG. It's gone in 4.0 and I can not find any addon that the option is attached to.

The option is there in 3.6:

[image: Blender 3.6]

But missing in 4.0:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. In the meantime I'm stuck with 3.6.

Comment: I have Render: Freestyle SVG Exporter by Folkert de Vries available in my add-ons list, that gives the Curves (.svg) option in the Export-menu.

Comment: @Jaco Are you sure? When I disable it, _Curves (.svg)_ ist still available in the _Export_ list. Must be something else.

Comment: You are correct, for some reason after enabling the function appeared in my list so i assumed it must've been the one i mentioned. After disabling the function is still listed so must be something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the *Curves (.svg)* option in my *Export* file formats but could not find any addon related to it at first either.

The problem is, when filtering for "svg" the resulting addons are not providing this option, and searching for "curves" gave me just one result which was not providing the export option.

However, searching for "curve" brought up the correct addon: **Add Curve: Curve Tools**.

[image: curve tools]

Comment: Of course. Its obvious after someone takes the time to think critically about it. Thanks. It hadn't occurred to me it could be part of another feature set / addon. ...or that I could have searched for the only other possible keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have 4.0.0 now, but it's certainly there in 4.0.1 and 4.0.2.

[image]